# Android move background continuously with animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

What I want to do is move the background horizontally and have it repeat infinitely.

I tried using an `ImageSwitcher` with animation to give this effect, but couldn't get it to work right. This is the code I have so farL

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

    private Animation animSlide;
    private ImageSwitcher image;
    private ImageView imagePop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.image_switcher);

        image.setFactory(this);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zc06);
        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        in.setDuration(10000);
        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        out.setDuration(10000);
        image.setInAnimation(in);
        image.setOutAnimation(out);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zc06);
                    }
                });
            }

        }, 0, 10000);

        Animation mZoomInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_in);

        Animation mZoomOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_out);
        imagePop.startAnimation(mZoomInAnimation);
        imagePop.startAnimation(mZoomOutAnimation);

    }

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView myView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using view animations? You really shouldn't be using them anymore... Use the new animation API instead. Anyway you can easily create an animation like that by having two `ImageViews` in your layout and translating them with a `ValueAnimator`. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Why don't you try to just animate the background yourself instead of using a `ViewSwitcher`? All you need is one simple `ValueAnimator`:

First add two identical `ImageViews` to your layout and set the same background image to both of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then use a `ValueAnimator` to animate their translationX property, but offset them by their width:

```
final ImageView backgroundOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_one);
final ImageView backgroundTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_two);

final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animator.setDuration(10000L);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        final float progress = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        final float width = backgroundOne.getWidth();
        final float translationX = width * progress;
        backgroundOne.setTranslationX(translationX);
        backgroundTwo.setTranslationX(translationX - width);
    }
});
animator.start();
```

This results in an continuous animation which repeats the background indefinitely and should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: In case you want to slow down the animation, increase the duration! :-)

Comment: You can reverse the animation by changing the ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, -1.0f) and backgroundTwo.setTranslation(translation + width)

Comment: Worked very well for me Thanks! +1

Answer (score 5):

you can use **[AndroidScrollingImageView](https://github.com/Q42/AndroidScrollingImageView)** Library, all you have to do is to define speed and the drawable source

```
<com.q42.android.scrollingimageview.ScrollingImageView
    android:id="@+id/scrolling_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    scrolling_image_view:speed="1dp"
    scrolling_image_view:src="@drawable/scrolling_background" />
```

**EDIT:**

as @Cliff Burton mentioned, you can rotate the view by 90 deg if you want to scroll vertically.

Comment: Is there a way to scroll vertically with this?

Comment: @CliffBurton I didn't try it before, but you could play with it, maybe you can add orientation in xml code, or maybe there a method to do that in java code, but those are just guesses.

Comment: I just realised that you can rotate the view by 90 deg if you want to scroll vertically...if you want you can update your answer with this solution ;)

Comment: @CliffBurton how to rotate the view by 90 deg. ?

Comment: @bhanukaushik I managed to rotate the view with the parameter `android:rotation="90"` in the `ScrollingImageView` view in the xml layout

Comment: ScrollingImageView : unable to set image programily