# android Position an image inside an ImageView animation

Tags: android, android-animation

i have imageView

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/spinner"/>
```

and image is 
[image]

i want create an animation which change position of image inside imageView

i tried this

```
android:scrollX="-80dp"
```

this in xml and static i want animation

Comment: TranslateAnimation?

Comment: How ? Translate animation done in image view not image inside

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894384/android-move-background-continuously-with-animation

Comment: not work with me 
i want to show 40dp of image at a time

Comment: Is it a single image, Are u looking for a animation something looks like pre loader?

Comment: exactly  like pre loader

Comment: @EssamGoda, Then it will be really easy, there will be several ways to do this, 
1.First one is make image GIF and use gif loader.
2. and second one is add all images to image array (resource int array) and run a recessive for loop until you want to show it, Hope this will help. If you want example let me know, I'll publish it tomorrow. Cheers !!

Comment: @KZoNE yes it is single image and i want as pre loader

Comment: @KZoNE thanks very much

Comment: use a custom `Drawable` class and implement the drawing in `draw(Canvas canvas)` method

Comment: @pskink ,please could show me how ?

Comment: by calling `Canvas#drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect, Rect, Paint)` method

Comment: Use thread and handler and set bitmap after certain sleep period in thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a thread and a handler where the thread sleeps for a certain amount of time and informs handler by sending message when it wakes up and handler will update the image in image view.

Create 4 Fields like below :

```
private ImageView mImageView;
private Handler mImageChangingHandler;
private int mCurrentImageIndex = 0;
private BackgroundThread mImageUpdateThread;
```

In `onCreate()` get the ImageView, spilt your bitmaps and add it to a list and create a handler which updates imageview. Here you should know the **number of individual bitmaps** which is in **main Bitmap**. Like :

```
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
Bitmap mainBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.anim);
//number of individual bitmaps, which you should know.
final int numberOfImages = 21;
//individual bitmap width
int bitmapWidth = mainBitmap.getWidth() / numberOfImages;
//individual bitmap height
int bitmapHeight = mainBitmap.getHeight();
//list which holds individual bitmaps.
final List<Bitmap> animBitmaps = new ArrayList<>(numberOfImages);
//split your bitmap in to individual bitmaps
for (int index = 0; index < numberOfImages; index++) {
    animBitmaps.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(mainBitmap, index * bitmapWidth, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight));
}
//set 1st bitmap to imageView.
mImageView.setImageBitmap(animBitmaps.get(mCurrentImageIndex));
mImageChangingHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //increament current bitmap index
        mCurrentImageIndex++;
        //if current index is greater than the number of images, reset it to 0
        if (mCurrentImageIndex > numberOfImages - 1) {
            mCurrentImageIndex = 0;
        }
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(animBitmaps.get(mCurrentImageIndex));
            return true;
    }
});
//Create the background thread by passing the handler and start.
mImageUpdateThread = new BackgroundThread(mImageChangingHandler);
mImageUpdateThread.setRunning(true);
mImageUpdateThread.start();
```

And This will be your `BackgroundThread.class` :

```
public static class BackgroundThread extends Thread {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mRunning;

    public BackgroundThread(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        mRunning = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (mRunning) {
            try {
                //this sleeps for 100 milliseconds
                sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //send message to handler after sleep
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in `onDestroy()` stop the thread. Like :

```
mImageUpdateThread.setRunning(false);
boolean stopThread = true;
    while (stopThread) {
        try {
            mImageUpdateThread.join();
            //thread already stopped
            stopThread = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
mImageUpdateThread = null;
```

**Note :** If you want to increase the update speed, reduce the sleep time in thread.