# I want make image slider like Marquee image?

Tags: android, imageview, marquee

http://www.talk4u.in/TagoreAcadmy/marque.html

this my url that is in html format now i want bulid image slider like that but i don't want to use webview .i want develop using android view 
and image move should be restart from to ending like a globe .

i have multipal image url fatch from mysql database than show on slider like marquee.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ValueAnimator and setTranslationX with "two images".

See this: [Android move background continuously with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894384/android-move-background-continuously-with-animation)

In addition, in your case, you need to change scrolling direction.
Note that "Modified" below.

```
final ImageView backgroundOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_one);
final ImageView backgroundTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_two);    
final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, -1.0f); // Modified
animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animator.setDuration(10000L);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        final float progress = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        final float width = backgroundOne.getWidth();
        final float translationX = width * progress;
        backgroundOne.setTranslationX(translationX);
        backgroundTwo.setTranslationX(translationX - width);
    }
});
animator.start();
```

---

**Edit1:**

If you want use images from server, I suggest you to use Picasso image library.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

1. Add picasso dependency to Build.gradle file. (

   - Add below into dependencies 
     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
   - and press sync button of top of Android studio
2. Load images with picasso.

   ```
   final ImageView backgroundOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_one);
   final ImageView backgroundTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_two);

   Picasso.with(this).load("http://www.talk4u.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cropped-logo2.png").into(backgroundOne);

   Picasso.with(this).load("http://www.talk4u.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/cropped-logo2.png").into(backgroundTwo);

   final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, -1.0f); // Modified
   animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
   animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
   animator.setDuration(10000L);
   animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
           final float progress = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
           final float width = backgroundOne.getWidth();
           final float translationX = width * progress;
           backgroundOne.setTranslationX(translationX);
           backgroundTwo.setTranslationX(translationX - width);
       }
   });

   animator.start();
   ```

   - Add network permission to access internet.

Comment: Oh, thank you cricket_007. I Couldn't fix that code block.