# React Native move background continuously with animation

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a moving background in react native to move continusely from left to right or from bottom to top.

I found a code for Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894384/android-move-background-continuously-with-animation) but can't make a similar react native code:

[image]

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lottie: http://airbnb.io/lottie/

You would have to make the animation outside and then use it as a view with absolute position but it should work. That way you could control the flow.

Also, you could expose that native code in RN as a Native Module.

Answer (score 0):

I think this library will suit your needs
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scrolling-images

Install the lib
`npm install react-native-scrolling-images`

Then simply use the component.

```
<ScrollingBackground
      style={styles.scrollingBackground}
      speed={20}
      direction={"left"}
      images={[require("./assets/greenOrange.png"),require("./assets/blueOrange.png")]}
      useNativeDriver={true}
    />
```

PS1: You need to always set backgroundColor style property. Otherwise you will get an error.

```
scrollingBackground: {
backgroundColor: "#0B7483"
```

}

PS2: They will turn the image 90 deg when you use left/right direction. What i did is to manually flip the image 90 deg.