# Both Object- and ValueAnimator jumps when Duration is set above API LvL 24

Tags: android, animation

I am using ObjectAnimator to move an ImageView cntinuously from the top to the bottton of the screen. The code is the following:

```
    ObjectAnimator animate;
    animate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ImageView, "translationY" ,0 ,screenHeight);
    animate.setDuration(time);
    animate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animate.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    animate.start();
```

After the animation is started I change the Duration of the animtaion every `x` seconds. The animation is flawless but whenever I run the app on a phone or emulator that uses Android 7.0 (API lvl 24) or above, every time I change the Duration the Image skips frames and jumps further in the animation. 
I lower the Duration every time the ImageView arrives at the botton of the screen with `10ms`. Also the jump becomes every time a bit greater so at the very beginning at the first `setDuration` there is none and the a little and then bigger and bigger.
I tried looking for an answere but I couldn´t find any so I hoped some Developer recognise this and helps me out.

Comment: i gave you the solution, didnt i? either use `TimeAnimator` or dont change the duration when `ObjectAnimator` is running

Comment: No you didn´t... And yes I want to change the duration and I want to use ObjectAnimator. There should be a sulotion

Comment: and there is: do not change the duration when it is running

Comment: I want to achive a flawless animation if I stop it it will be worse

Comment: why would you stop it? dont you think that all you want to do is one workarand? set duration while running, stopping to set duration, etc

Comment: it is somewhat complicated: I use a very long image and on the Image is the same pattern 3 times. I use the Image as backgrouond and the pattern of the Image isn´t the same height as the size of the screen. the image is streched out of the sreen. thats why I can´t/ don´t want to stop it and run the animation every time over and over again because the pattern doesn´t arrive at the bottom of the screen when I change the duration, so it would jump back to the start

Comment: why would you ever change the duration? whats the reason for that?

Comment: Because its a game. It gets ´harder´

Comment: then use right `Interpolator`, not linear one - most likely [AccelerateInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateInterpolator.html), if the acceleration provided is not what you want (you can however try different factor in `new AccelerateInterpolator(float factor)`) make a custom `Interpolator`

Comment: I dont want it to accelerate constantly but I want it to be faster after every round.

Comment: `"After the animation is started I change the Duration of the animtaion every x seconds."` so you change the duration after every round or after every x seconds? and the speed has to be constant during every round and increase when you go level up?

Comment: after every round which is also x seconds because the the Duration of a round is every time somewhat lower

Comment: so you are trying to call `setDuration` while animation is running? and not for example when it is about to repeat? if so it will not work, all you need is a custom interpolator or set of values to animate from/to - in the second solution the change will not be smooth thou...

Comment: and the second solution looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/Eqhf9Htj)

Comment: And that´s exactly my problem: it works **perfect** up to android 7.0

Comment: because you are calling `setDuration` when animator is running - do not do that - try the [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/Eqhf9Htj) i posted, what do you see when you run it?

Comment: it does something that for sure. Not really what I want to see tho. May I contact you somewhere else where I can send you images so you can understand the situation better?

Comment: paste them here https://pasteboard.co/ - of course make them relatively small - i dont want  to download megs of bytes

Comment: here: https://pasteboard.co/GR99Zhs.png  I move the image with 1/3 of the Imageheight (thats one segment) and then I set it back to the top. That´s how I achieve a smooth loop

Comment: ok so your file has three segments = three levels - each level should be scrolled faster - for example each segment has 10000 pixels and level 1 is shown in 10 seconds, level 2 in 8 secs and level 3 in 6 seconds, what next?

Comment: no my file has three times the same segment. This way I can achieve that the image cover the full screen and create a flawless animation

Comment: basicly this one here but I use just one long image instead of more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894384/android-move-background-continuously-with-animation

Comment: so `TimeAnimator` is your friend, see: https://pastebin.com/raw/Jc0fzQNK

Comment: i don´t really undertand that code but just to make sure, does that work like this?: http://gifmaker.me/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2017102902UybZyOcyDTktQOBEhM4e7m&file=output_PXTuXd.gif

Comment: just run it - download the road image from https://pasteboard.co/GRaQUoD.png and simply call `setContentView(new Road(this));`inside `Activity#onCreate` method

Comment: Yes it does! :D Now I have a few question: how do I change the direcion? It should go from top to bottom. As I said the large image contains 3 segments so is it possible to move the large image as shown in the gif? Is it possible to change the duration freely in other methods and not at every round in the TimeAnimator? Is it possible to make the canvas smaller or add it to a Layout bacause I have other thing on the screen along whit the that. With that said can I move it to the background so everything above will be seen?

Comment: you want the different speed then change `speed` field, for custom views see https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: and no, your image does not need to have 3 identical segments - see my road.png

Comment: yes I fugured that out. still how do I change a `speed`variable in the Road class from another class? also how do I stop/cancel the `animation` in another class? I did read the article but still I can´t figure out how to resize the canvas

Comment: Perfect would be if I could somehow use code you passed me directly on my existing image, is it possible? Because I don´t really need the canvas

Comment: How do I achieve the same animation loop on one Image without using a canvas?

Comment: you cannot: if you want to use `imageview` you need a duplicated image (with two identical segments placed horizontally)

Comment: can I just do it as I shown i the gif? hava a long `imageview` with 3 segments and move it 1/3 and set it back to top

Comment: So tell me, is it possible to achieve the same (or very similar) affect as with Value,- ObjectAnimator using TimeAnimator on `imageview` and not canvas?

Comment: sure it is, you will need to rewrite my logic to achieve that, but does it really pays off?

Comment: i tried to describe why your solution with the canvas doesn´t fit in my app. If it pays off? I don´t really know anymore... All I wanted is animate my `imageview` in a loop and change it´s duration while its running.

Comment: also I have quasi no idea how TimeAnimator works so I have 0 idea how to achive an even similar effect so it is going to be a tough one...

Comment: so what do you expect from me? to change it to ValueAnimator with not fixed duration?

Comment: I´m afraid if it were ValueAnimator it would skip and jump every time I change the duartion again... Actually I want to get rid of the canvas  and have an Animator spacific to an `imageview`

Comment: ok so do you think `ImageView` does not use `Canvas`? whats the difference if you use `ImageView` or `Road` view?

Comment: I don´t really know what canvas supposed to be. I saw in your code that you animate the canvas. All i ment is that I don´t know how to handel a canvas the way you did (resize / make it to the background / andjust its position on the screen), while I have an existing `imageview` with the positoin set where I wanted it to have (the road isn´t fullscreen), so if it would be possible I would like to animate that `iamgeview`

Comment: so feel free to rewrite my code: all you need is to call `imageView.setTranslationY` in the listener

Comment: where exactly? and is a big problem to delete `onDraw(...)` or is it important? how do iI delete the canvas?

Comment: just create a `TimeAnimator`, add listener and start it, inside listener call `imageView.setTranslationY` method

Comment: yeah I know that... but its a TImaAnimator. I have no clue what comes in the TimeListener... If I call `imageview.setTranslation(toataltime)` or something like that the image will scroll throught the screen and then disapear. That´s ofcourse not what I want I need somthing like yours without the canvas but I don´t understad the variables in you code that why I can´t use it on my own.

Comment: whit the ObjectAnimator was it easy to create a loop

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeAnimator.TimeListener.html

Comment: thanks I already did read the article but I didn´t get smarter how to craete a loop animation

Comment: do you know `%` operator in java?

Comment: not really.....

Comment: okay I looked it up now I know what it does but how is that supposed to help me?

Comment: so what is the result of `3 % 4`, `4 % 4`, `5 % 4`, `9 % 4` etc ?

Comment: `75` `0` `25` `25` if I´m not mistaking

Comment: no: `3` `0` `1` `1`

Comment: doesnt it give back the remainder? like 3/4 = 0.75 so it´s `75`?

Comment: http://www.java67.com/2014/11/modulo-or-remainder-operator-in-java.html

Comment: alraight now I understand it but still how is it supposed to hep me?

Comment: you really, really dont see the point? try `imageview.setTranslationY(toataltime % 2000)`

Comment: now heres the problem: in `imageview.setTranslationY(toataltime % 2000 * factor)` I additionally have factor so the I can make the animation faster but every variable has to be defined final in it so it isn´t possible to change it... Any idea on that?

Comment: besides that I don´t know how to change the ´duration´ it works quite nicely :)

Comment: okay forgot the 2. comment above I just realised it doesn´t make any sence... still how can I achieve a flexible ´duration´ ?

Comment: have you seen `float speed = 1;` in my code?

Comment: yes but you don´t use `.setTranslationY()` but `.translate` on the canvas

Comment: and the parameters within the `onTImeUpdate` method has to be defined as final

Comment: okay so here is something I tried: `imageview.setTranslationY(((totalTime * speed)  % 2000)` now every time i change `speed` (float) the `imageview` jumps again

Comment: refer to my original [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/Jc0fzQNK) and see where (and how) `speed` field is used

Comment: so now I have to combine `y += deltaTime * speed` and this `toataltime % 2000`

Comment: ok and where (and what for) `y` is used? is it really that hard to analyze those few lines of code?

Comment: for the `setTranslationY(y)`

Comment: so whats your problem actually?

Comment: the value of `y` will be greater only which means in `setTranslationY()` the `imagewiev` will only slide toward the bottom and now I don´t know how to set it back

Comment: do you know `%` operator in java?

Comment: yes, you showed me it :)

Comment: so simply use it

Comment: wow it is actrually working, holy heck, thanks! Now my neyt question is if it´s possible to use `int` or something rather `float` to change the overall speed? it makes it kind difficult that I have to work with float while the other animations use regular aniamtions

Comment: also it is a little bit laggy :(

Comment: hey! just wanted to let you know that I now completed my code and it´s working! Also I wanted to thank you that much help you gave me. So thank you very much! :)

Comment: sure, your welcome