# How to make android animated drawable background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to make an animated drawable background for my android app.
Is possible to make an animated background using `<layer-list>` and `<animation-list>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android Lollipop (API level 21) it is possible to implement using [AnimatedVectorDrawable.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable)
FOr It's tutorial take a look [here](https://mobikul.com/use-animated-vector-drawable-app/)

There are also tools that will help to animate vector drawable [shapeshifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) and you would also want to take a look at this post from the author of the tool shapeshifter [An Introduction to Icon Animation Techniques.](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html) For basic tutorial of Shapeshifter take a look [here](https://sourcediving.com/android-recipes-the-easy-path-to-animated-icons-878bffcb0920)

Other than that if you need to use External library then you would like to look [here](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView)

Comment: Can I make an animated background without using vector images?

Comment: Well definetily if paths are commpatible then you could create an animation and put that as background howeve how to animate that without any click event is omething i am not quiet sure about

Comment: btw may i ask what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I want to make an animated gradient background.

Comment: if you want drawable you can get that by this :https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation

Comment: if you want gradient background here is a nice tutorial:http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/animated-gradient-background-in-android/

Comment: here is an similar question this would certainly help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894384/android-move-background-continuously-with-animation

Comment: glad i could  help :-) Keep coding